# How to make the condition to re-execute, once the condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Function stopped working after the condition is satisfied. My condition is too execute until the length of the array is lesser than equal to 4 ( <= 4) . So, it correctly executes till the length gets to 5 ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ) but then it stops there, even at 4 the condition should be running but it moves to the else function,

Here is my code:

```js
  onPressSelectionHandler(day) {
    this.state.selectedDateByOnPress <= 4 ? (
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedDateByOnPress: [
          ...(prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.some(d => d.dateString === day.dateString)
            ? prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.filter(d => d.dateString !== day.dateString)
            : [...prevState.selectedDateByOnPress, day])
        ],
        daysing: day
      }))
    ) : (
      <Text>Not allowed</Text>
    );
  }
```

So, the above function set the state on each onPress activity shoots on, but i want to limit the state "selectedDateByOnPress" to max of 5. So i kept the condition with length.

But, while pressing on again, the condition is moving to the  , what i need is , when the length reaches to 4, then the first function should only needs to get executed. But i dont know why its moving on . Hope everybody understand the problem.

Comment: I suggest refactoring this code into something readable - might help you understand what's going on

Comment: Anyway, `selectedDateByOnPress` seems to be an array, you cannot just compare an array with `<=4`... maybe you want `selectedDateByOnPress.length` ?

Comment: Closing Text is missing </Text>

Comment: What i need is, this.setState should only execute untill the length is <= 4, whats happening is it getting executes till length is 4, but when the length is = to 4 its going to <Text>.

Comment: oops sorry, its an typo the code is selectedDateByOnPress.lenght only @enapupe